# How to make a dynamic plot of a holed circle using "Manipulate"

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, geometry

I would like to make a dynamic circle with the inner radius ($R_a(t)$) moving to $R_b$ like the image below. I had difficulty using Manipulate and leaving the intersections colored as in the image. Would anyone know how to do it that way?

Thank you very much for your attention!

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! as already requested, in general please post the code you've tried so far so others can copy-and-paste and fiddle with it. You might find it useful to construct this as three `Disk`s of decreasing radius stacked one on top of the other, or as two `Annulus`es.

Comment: Excellent question applicable to many industries such as oil/gas, EM, transmission lines, and all the STEM fields really. I request that you modify your title to help search engines so as to bring more visitors to this page. The word "graph" has a different usage in Math/CS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
{minradiusa, radiusb, radiusr} = {.2, .85, 1};
```

***Labeled arrow annotations:***

```
labeledArrows[r_] := {PointSize[Medium], Point[{0, 0}], 
  MapThread[{
     Arrowheads[{{.025, 1}, 
         {Automatic, .5, Graphics[{Text[Style[#, 16], {0, 0}, {0, -1.2}, #2]}]}}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, #3 {Cos[#4 Pi/4], Sin[#4 Pi/4]}}]} &, 
   {{#<>"(t)", ##2}& @@ (ToString[Subscript[R, #], StandardForm] & /@ {"a", "r", "b"}),
   {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}}, 
   {r, radiusr, radiusb}, 
   {5, 1, 7}}]}

Graphics @ labeledArrows[.5]
```

[image]

***Animate + Graphics:***

Alternatively, use [`Annulus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annulus.html) + [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) + [`Animate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html):

```
Animate[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray],
   LightYellow, Annulus[{0, 0}, {rt, radiusb}], 
   LightGray, Annulus[{0, 0}, {radiusb, radiusr}],
   Opacity[1], Black, labeledArrows[rt]},
   PlotLabel -> Style[PromptForm[Area, 
     Pane[Round[ Pi (radiusb^2 - rt^2), .001], ImageSize -> {50, 20}]], 16, Black]], 
 {rt, minradiusa, radiusb}]
```

[image]

***Animation without controls:***

```
frames = Table[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], LightYellow, 
     Annulus[{0, 0}, {rt, radiusb}], LightGray, 
     Annulus[{0, 0}, {radiusb, radiusr}], 
     Opacity[1], Black, labeledArrows[rt]},
   PlotLabel -> Style[PromptForm[Area, 
     Pane[Round[ Pi (radiusb^2 - rt^2), .001], ImageSize -> {50, 20}]], 16, Black]], 
   {rt, Most@Subdivide[minradiusa, radiusb, 100]}];

 Export["dynamicradius.gif", frames, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

[image]

***Manipulate + ParametricPlot***

Use [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) with the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html), [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html), and use `labeledArrows[]` as [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html). Dynamically control first element of the mesh values using [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html):

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  r { Cos @ t,  Sin @ t}, {t, 0 , 2 Pi}, {r, minradiusa, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{rt, radiusb, radiusr}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Thick, 
  Epilog -> labeledArrows[rt], 
  MeshShading -> {White, LightYellow, LightGray}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotPoints -> 90, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 600
  PlotLabel -> Style[PromptForm[Area, 
     Pane[Round[ Pi (radiusb^2 - rt^2), .001], ImageSize -> {50, 20}]], 16, Black]], 
 {{rt, .3, Style[ToString[Subscript[R, a], StandardForm] <> "(t)", 14]}, 
   .2, .85, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! Can i save an animate video without the "manipulation controls" at the top?

Comment: @Felipe, please see the update.

Answer (score 6):

A starting point.

```
annulus = RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 2.3], Disk[{0, 0}, 2]];
regint[r_] := RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 2.3], Disk[{0, 0}, r]];
ani = Animate[
  Show[Region[regint[r], 
    BaseStyle -> {Blend[{LightYellow, Orange}, .15], 
      EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]]}], 
   Region[annulus, 
    BaseStyle -> {Gray, EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]]}], 
   PlotLabel -> "Area = " <> ToString[RegionMeasure@regint[r]]], {r, 
   1, 2}]
Export["test.gif", ani, "ControlAppearance" -> None, 
 "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity, ImageSize -> Large]

(* Export["test.mp4", ani, "ControlAppearance" -> None, FrameRate -> 20, 
 "AnimationDuration" -> 10, ImageSize -> Large] *)
```

[image]